# Abrir arquivo Excel em BINARY_SAFE

Tags: php, microsoft-excel

Gostaria de, em PHP, abrir uma planilha XLS já existente, inserir dados nas colunas, gravar e fechar o arquivo.
Existe alguma função ou API para esse tipo de tratamento, que abra o arquivo em `BINARY_SAFE` e me permita esse tipo de manipulação?

Comment: Existe a biblioteca [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: mas a phpexcel ela cria o arquivo e eu quero apenas manipular um já existente. ou ele manipula também?

Comment: Esse é o problema de você não dizer o que tentou/pesquisou: alguém sugere alguma coisa e você diz *"mas isso eu já conheço/não me serve porque..."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com [phpexcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) é possivel carregar e manipular a planilha, tendo como exemplo um planilha com duas colunas nome e email, e as seguintes linhas:

```
1 -       A              B
2 - joão da silva   joao@gmail.com
3 - maria oliveira  maria@gmail.com
```

Esse código carrega o arquivo clientes.xls, faz adicição de um novo cliente e salva a planilha. Essa respostas foi baseda no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797103/how-to-open-an-excel-file-with-phpexcel-for-both-reading-and-writing)

```
<?php

set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$fileType = 'Excel5';
$fileName = 'clientes.xls';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A4', 'jose');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B4', 'jose@gmail.com');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);
$objWriter->save($fileName);
```